# Java instantiating a class in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, object

Currently my code instantiates a class for a number of cores one after the other but I would like to create a loop that instantiates the class detectors() for an arbitrary number of cores, running concurrently.

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); // finds the number of available threads

    detectors.getStartingConditions(); 

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        detectors core1= new detectors();
        detectors core2= new detectors();
        detectors core3= new detectors();
        //etc

        core1.start();
        core2.start();
        core3.start();
        //etc

        try 
        { // wait for completion of all thread and then sum
            core1.join();
            core2.join();
            core3.join();
            //etc
        } 
    catch(InterruptedException IntExp) {}         

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("That took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
```

My attempt at a solution:

I created a array of objects as follows but the processor cores run one after the other as opposed to concurrently.

edit: the cores now run concurrently.

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); // finds the number of available threads
detectors[] theCores = new detectors[processors];

    detectors.getStartingConditions(); 

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        for(int i = 0; i <= processors-1; i++){
        theCores[i] = new detectors();
        theCores[i].start();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= processors-1; i++){
        try{
        theCores[i].join();}

        catch(InterruptedException IntExp) {} 
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("That took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
```

Comment: You're waiting for join from process 0 before you even create process 1.

Comment: Thanks, I will update the post with the correction - i think now the code is working but if you could check it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates threads and joins it before creating the next thread. That causes the sequential execution. You have to use two loops instead. The first loop creates all threads, whereas the second loop joins all threads.

```
for (int i = 0; i < processors; ++i) {
    theCores[i] = new detectors();
    theCores[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < processors; ++i) {
    try {
        theCores[i].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        RuntimeException re = new RuntimeException("unsupported interruption", ie);
        for (++i; i < processors; ++i) {
            try {
                theCores[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                re.addSuppressed(e);
            }
        }
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a trivial error, my mistake. Is the try and catch code needed in the second loop or not?

Comment: I have added throws InteruptedException to the whole method now but what is best practice to catch it? Where should the catch statement from the new solution code be moved to?

Comment: I have added code for correct handling of _InterruptedException_.